# Two threads - reading text from STDIN and sending it through the pipe

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I wanna create two threads - one will be reading the string from the stdin, and the other will display it on the screen (communication through pipes). How can I do that? This is what I've wrote so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/stat.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>

int first[2];

void *input(void *ptr)
{
   close(first[1]);

   while(1)
   {
      char str[10];
      int result;

      read(STDIN_FILENO, str, 10);

      result = read(first[0], &str, 1);
      if(result != 1)
      {
         perror("read");
         exit(3);
      }

      printf("Reader: %s\n", str);
   }
}

void *output(void *ptr)
{
   close(first[0]);

   int result;
   char str[10];

   while(1)
   {
      result = write(first[1], &str, 1);
      if(result != 1)
      {
         perror("write");
         exit(2);
      }

      printf("Writer: %s\n", str);
   }
}

int main()
{
   pthread_t t1, t2;

   pthread_create(&t1, NULL, input, NULL);
   pthread_create(&t2, NULL, output, NULL);

   pthread_join(t1, NULL);
   pthread_join(t2, NULL);

   return 0;
}
```

I can compile it, but trying to run it shows an error "write: Bad file descriptor". I actually counldn't find any decent tutorial on pipes, only a couple of short codes. How should I do this?

Comment: There is no code to create a pipe. See `man 3 pipe`. Also concurrent access to share resources (`first` here) shall be synchronised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You have your directions of read/write to the pipe mixed up, and you're closing the pipe in your threads.
- You need to check how many bytes you read from stdin and send to the pipe.
- You can't use printf() directly on the data you read from the pipe, that data might not be a string (it might not be nul terminated, or it might be binary data)
- You need to actually create the pipe.

Here's what you want the "input" thread to do:

1. read from stdin
2. write data read in step 1 to the pipe

And the "output" thread:

1. read from the pipe
2. write data read in step 1 to stdout

So this should be:

```
void *input(void *ptr)
{

   while(1)
   {
      char str[10];
      int result;

      result = read(STDIN_FILENO, str, sizeof str);
      if (result <= 0) 
      {
         if(result == -1)
            perror("read");
         close(first[1]);
         return NULL;
      }
      if(write(first[1], str, result) != result)
      {
         perror("write");
         exit(3);
      }

      printf("Reader: %s\n", str);
   }
}

void *output(void *ptr)
{

   int result;
   char str[10];

   while(1)
   {
      result = read(first[0], str, sizeof str);
      if(result <= 0)
      {
         if(result == -1)
            perror("read");
         close(first[0]);
         return NULL;
      }

      if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, str, result) != result) {
          perror("write");
          exit(4);
      }
   }
}

int main()
{
   pthread_t t1, t2;
   pipe(first);
...
}
```